# what are closed sets in $L^{1}(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Consider, $L^{1}(\mathbb R)$= The space of Lebesgue integrable functions on $\mathbb R$; for $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb R),$ we define its norm, by $\|f\|_{L^{1}}=\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)| dx$; It is well-known that, $(L^{1}(\mathbb R), \|\cdot\|_{L^{1}})$ is a a complete norm linear space(Banach space).

Put, $A=\{f\in L^{1}(\mathbb R): f^{2}\in L^{1}(\mathbb R)\}$(=$L^{1}\cap L^{2}$).

> **My Questions**:(1) Is $A$ is closed in $L^{1}(\mathbb R)$ ? (2) Is any thing known about the closed sets(characterization) in $L^{1}(\mathbb R)$ ?

( Trivial Examples of closed sets in $L^{1}$: one may consider, (a) closed balls; then (i)its finite union; and (ii) its inter sections)

Thanks,

Comment: Open balls are open sets, like in any metric space, and so their complement is closed. I don't think this qualifies as a closed ball in your view, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is not closed. Take any function $f\in L^1$ such that $f$ is not in $L^2$, then approximate it by functions in $A$.

I.e. $f(x) = \chi_{(0,1)}(x) x^{-1/2}$, then $f\in L^1$, $f\not\in L^2$. Define
$f_n(x) = \min(n,f(x))$. Then $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$, $\|f_n\|_{L^2}\to\infty$.

As to your second question: sets like $\{f\in L^1: \ f\ge 0 \}$ are closed as well.

Comment: Why $f_{n}\in L^{1}(\mathbb R)$ ?(see, $f_{n}(x)=n$ for $x\notin (0,1)$, so $f_{n}$ can not be in $L^{1}$; ); thanks;

Comment: I think daw meant $f_n(x)=\min(n,f(x))$. Essentially you want to truncate $f$ when it is too large

Comment: Ofc it should be min instead of max, thanks for spotting.